# What do CI, CIM, CID, CIB mean?

Tags: abbreviations, euphemisms

I was talking to a friend about a girl, and he mentioned that “She can pretty much CI anything, CIB, CIM or CID.” I’m wondering what these mean. The context was sexual experience. Sorry if I missed some letters; English is not my primary language.

Comment: What was the context?

Comment: About ones sexual experiences.

Comment: Hmm my intuition suspects "come in [orifice]" but it doesn't quite fit the sentence as you wrote it.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Yeah . . . CIB, and CIM butt and mouth respectively.  D????  I'm a doctor and I can't think of a suitable orifice that starts with a D ...

Comment: @David Perhaps the last one was actually CIT? For breasts.

Answer (score 3):

From the context it appears to mean “cum in,” and your friend is suggesting that the girl engages in a variety of sexual acts. “She can pretty much [take it in] anything,” with *[CIM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cim)* meaning “in mouth” (oral sex) and *CIB* “in butt” (anal sex). *CID* might mean “in deep” (without a condom), or it could be the similar-sounding *CIT,* a sex act involving the breasts.

I haven’t heard *CI* used this way personally – it’s more commonly used to mean “confidential informant” (snitch) on cop shows – but I have heard the similar abbreviation *PIV* “penis in vagina.”

In the future, the easiest way to get the meaning of things like this is to laugh in response to your friend’s joke, then ask something like, “That’s a new one to me! What is it?”

Comment: I don't really understand how this would fit the usage of "she can pretty much CI anything", however. Go figure.

Comment: @MrHen I agree, it's a weird construction. I suspect that the speaker was a bit idiosyncratic, or that the OP misheard slightly, not being familiar with the terms. I could see “She can pretty much **do** CI anything,” for example.

Comment: According to Urban Dictionary, _CID_ can be _Cum In Deep_, which apparently means to come inside someone without a condom.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks! I've added that information to the answer.